# MySQL Query join 3 Tables (2 Tables have Data and 1 dont have Data)

Tags: php, mysql

I have make a Query To Find NetAmount2017, NetAmount2016 And Budget(2017) to represent it into a graph bar chart via HTML. Here is the Query.

```
$query:"SELECT x.netamt2017,z.netamt2016, y.budget, y.store_name
FROM
(
SELECT sum(a.netamt) as netamt2017, b.store_name 
FROM site_sales a JOIN site_store b ON b.storenum = a.storenum 
WHERE a.busidate >= '$date1' AND a.busidate <='$date2' AND a.storenum IN 
($storenum)
GROUP BY a.storenum
) x //This is to Find NetAmount2017

inner join
(
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN c.busidate BETWEEN '$date111' AND '$date211' THEN c.budget 
ELSE 0 END) as budget,
b.store_name
FROM site_kpimthslsbgt c JOIN site_store b ON b.storenum = c.storenum 
WHERE c.storenum IN ($storenum)
GROUP BY c.storenum
) y //This is to Find Budget
on x.store_name = y.store_name
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT sum(a.netamt) as netamt2016, b.store_name 
FROM site_sales a JOIN site_store b ON b.storenum = a.storenum 
WHERE a.busidate >= '$date1234' AND a.busidate <='$date2234' AND a.storenum 
IN ($storenum)
GROUP BY a.storenum
) z //This is to Find NetAmount2016
on y.store_name = z.store_name"
```

This Query is perfectly working, For Example Outlet (A,B,C,D,E) have Data 2016, 2017 And Budget. So the Result will be appear like this below [image: Result]

The Problem Occur When Some of the Outlets do not have Data in 2016, but have Data in 2017 and Budget. For Example, Outlet F have data 2017 and budget but dont have 2016. The expected result should come out with 2017 and budget only if it do not have data 2016. It will show 2 Bar chart only (Blue and Green Bars)

Comment: I think your query is too complex for you to expect a surgically-precise answer, at least not without a lot more sample data and information.  Can you rephrase your question using a simpler query and data set?

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design